# D3 triangular gradient

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to make a gradient inside a D3 svg triangle, with different colors from each corner, and I don't even know if it's physically possible. I dug through documentation and previous questions, but still no answers. This is current code:

```
var svgDefs = svg.append('defs');

        var gradient1 = svgDefs.append("radialGradient")
            .attr("id", "svgGradientBlack")
            .attr("cx", "50%")
            .attr("cy", "0%")
            .attr("r", "70%")

        gradient1.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "70%")
            .attr("stop-color", "black")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1)

        gradient1.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "white")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1);
        
        var gradient2 = svgDefs.append("radialGradient")
            .attr("id", "svgGradientBlue")
            .attr("cx", "0%")
            .attr("cy", "100%")
            .attr("r", "70%")

        gradient2.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "70%")
            .attr("stop-color", "blue")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1)

        gradient2.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "white")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1);

        var gradient2 = svgDefs.append("radialGradient")
            .attr("id", "svgGradientRed")
            .attr("cx", "100%")
            .attr("cy", "100%")
            .attr("r", "70%")

        gradient2.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "70%")
            .attr("stop-color", "Red")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1)

        gradient2.append("stop") 
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "white")
            .attr("stop-oppacity", 1);
        

        var trianglePoints = [[xScale(0), yScale(0)], [xScale(1), yScale(0)],[xScale(0.5), yScale(1)]];

        console.log(trianglePoints);

        svg.append('polyline')
            .attr('points', trianglePoints)
            .style('fill', "url(#svgGradientBlack)")
            .style('fill', "url(#svgGradientBlue)")
            .style('fill', "url(#svgGradientRed)");
```

I tried using linear, but it's well... linear. Radial also didn't work, as I can't stack two different fills on one polyline.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can with a **conic** gradient but I should mention I don't know anything about D3.

OK, so I'm gonna cheat a little by using CSS inside **foreignObject** because I'm a bit lazy to use pure SVG...

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <foreignObject width="100" height="100">

  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:conic-gradient(red,green,blue);"></div>

 </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

NB: As for restricting the gradient within a triangle lookup SVG blending filter "source-in" to get the gradient to crop within a shape.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feBlend

I hope this helps.